# Codeigniter can't access colum from database

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I tried to add 1 more column in my code, the column "itemid" to be used but I get strange error when I did everything how its supposed, the error message: "Undefined index: item_id".

My model:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->proTable   = 'web_store';
    $this->transTable = 'purchases_users';
    $this->GameRewards = 'users_items';
}

/*
 * Fetch products data from the database
 * @param id returns a single record if specified, otherwise all records
 */
public function getRows($id = ''){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->proTable);
    $this->db->where('status', '1');
    if($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row_array();
    }else{
        $this->db->order_by('Title', 'asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
    }
    
    // return fetched data
    return !empty($result)?$result:false;
}

/*
 * Insert data in the database
 * @param data array
 */
public function insertTransaction($data){
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->transTable,$data);
    return $insert?true:false;
}

/*
 * Insert data in the database
 * @param data array
 */
public function insertGameRewards($data){
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->GameRewards,$data);
    return $insert?true:false;
}
```

My Paypal controller:

```
function  __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('paypal_lib');
    $this->load->model('product');
}
 
function success(){
    // Get user session (is it logged in the webpage)
    $Session = $this->session->userdata("Player_Logged");
    
    if($Session) {
    // Get the transaction data
    $paypalInfo = $this->input->post();
    $data['item_name']= $paypalInfo['item_name'];
    $data['item_number']= $paypalInfo['item_number'];
    $data['item_idr']= $paypalInfo['item_idr'];
    $data['txn_id'] = $paypalInfo["txn_id"];
    $data['payment_amt'] = $paypalInfo["payment_gross"];
    $data['currency_code'] = $paypalInfo["mc_currency"];
    $data['status'] = $paypalInfo["payment_status"];
    
    // Get user ID from 'users' table.
    $IGN = $this->session->userdata['Player_Logged']['id'];


    // Pass the transaction data to view
    $this->load->view('paypal/success', $data);
            // Insert the transaction data in the database
                // This "custom" is old method by documentation, updated by me :P ('user_id' is 'UserID' [I changed column name in database])
            //$datatobase['user_id']    = $paypalInfo["custom"];
            $datatobase['UserID']   = $IGN;
            $datatobase['PackageID']    = $paypalInfo["item_number"];
            // ne barai taka e
            $datatobase['itemid']   = $paypalInfo["item_idr"];
            $datatobase['txn_id']   = $paypalInfo["txn_id"];
            $datatobase['payment_gross']    = $paypalInfo["mc_gross"];
            $datatobase['currency_code']    = $paypalInfo["mc_currency"];
            $datatobase['payer_email']  = $paypalInfo["payer_email"];
            $datatobase['payment_status'] = $paypalInfo["payment_status"];

            // Insert the gamerewards data in the database
            $rewardstobase['UserID']    = $IGN;
            $rewardstobase['ItemID']    = $paypalInfo["item_idr"];
            $rewardstobase['EnhID']     = "1957";
            $rewardstobase['Equipped']  = "0";
            $rewardstobase['Quantity']  = "1";
            $rewardstobase['Bank']      = "0";
            
            // Insert the transaction data in the database
            $this->product->insertTransaction($datatobase);
            // Insert the gamerewards data in the database
            $this->product->insertGameRewards($rewardstobase);
    } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Error</strong> Error :( ! You need to log in to your account first.
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
            $this->output->set_header('refresh:5; url=http://192.168.1.14/web/Home');
    }
}
 
function cancel(){
    // Load payment failed view
    $this->load->view('paypal/cancel');
 }
 
function ipn(){
    // Paypal posts the transaction data
    $paypalInfo = $this->input->post();
    
    if(!empty($paypalInfo)){
        // Validate and get the ipn response
        $ipnCheck = $this->paypal_lib->validate_ipn($paypalInfo);

        // Check whether the transaction is valid
        if($ipnCheck){
            // Insert the transaction data in the database
            $data['user_id']    = $paypalInfo["custom"];
            $data['product_id'] = $paypalInfo["item_number"];
            $data['txn_id'] = $paypalInfo["txn_id"];
            $data['payment_gross']  = $paypalInfo["mc_gross"];
            $data['currency_code']  = $paypalInfo["mc_currency"];
            $data['payer_email']    = $paypalInfo["payer_email"];
            $data['payment_status'] = $paypalInfo["payment_status"];

            $this->product->insertTransaction($data);
        }
    }
}
```

My product controller:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->proTable   = 'web_store';
    $this->transTable = 'purchases_users';
    $this->GameRewards = 'users_items';
}

/*
 * Fetch products data from the database
 * @param id returns a single record if specified, otherwise all records
 */
public function getRows($id = ''){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->proTable);
    $this->db->where('status', '1');
    if($id){
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->row_array();
    }else{
        $this->db->order_by('Title', 'asc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
    }
    
    // return fetched data
    return !empty($result)?$result:false;
}

/*
 * Insert data in the database
 * @param data array
 */
public function insertTransaction($data){
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->transTable,$data);
    return $insert?true:false;
}

/*
 * Insert data in the database
 * @param data array
 */
public function insertGameRewards($data){
    $insert = $this->db->insert($this->GameRewards,$data);
    return $insert?true:false;
}
```

I tried to add new field 'item_idr' and get column 'itemid' with the same method how other fields are get by this library but it didn't work. I get error message. Even more details of the error message I get:

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined index: item_idr
Filename: controllers/Paypal.php
Line Number: 20
Backtrace:
File: C:\laragon\www\web\application\controllers\Paypal.php
Line: 20
Function: _error_handler
File: C:\laragon\www\web\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't have the control named "item_idr" in your view.
In Paypal.php at line

`data['item_idr']= $paypalInfo['item_idr'];`

it takes info from

`$paypalInfo = $this->input->post();`

As a side note, you can use CI form library ([see CI documentation for form helper here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html)) to extract the $_POST values, so you can benefit from form validation and sanitation of entries.
Anyways... coming back...
you are taking $_POST['item_idr'] and that is the error you get. So it is unrelated to your table and database, but related to the fact that your view doesn't have any

`<input type="text" name="item_idr" id="item_idr">`

or similar

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answer, I don’t want to parse this data since i have product id, this item is just automatically import in database so someone who buys for example product 1, he will take the item depends on that product automatically.

Comment: problem is not resolved :/ , even if I get it in view , error is same. My point is to store it in database, as the example code I provided.

Comment: (1) please post the code in the view, too. 
(2) Also based on your error message: Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: item_idr Filename: controllers/Paypal.php Line Number: 20  so please post what exactly you have at line 20 of Paypal.php controller
(3) also state the version of CI you use, I assume it is a version 3 or below and not 4, as version 4 has substantial code changes...

Comment: Hello! Update, I managed to fix the problem. First I tried with array, didn't work, then I tried with php explode function, in the first controller I did this:
`$this->paypal_lib->add_field('custom', $product['itemid'].'-'.$product['BadgeID'].'-'.$product['itemid2'].'-'.$product['Coins']);`
and in second controller i did this:
`$rewardstobase['ItemID'] = $data['custom'][0];`.